# will a WAP work through a passive switch

Tags: wireless-access-point, switch, patch

I have a Comcast modem/router that currently provides internet to my house, but I want to upgrade and add a WAP and some ethernet drops around.  I have set up networks before, but I have never done one that involved a wireless router and a switch, so I am not entirely certain how to proceed, or if the outcome will depend on the specific capabilities of the hardware I use.

Here are my two best ideas for how it should be set up,

```
  │In                           │In
┌─┴─────┐   ┌──────┐          ┌─┴─────┐   ┌──────┐
│ISP Box├───┤Switch│          │ISP Box├───┤Switch│
└───────┘   └┬┬┬┬┬┬┘          └─┬─────┘   └─┬┬┬┬┬┘
  ┌──────────┘│││││             │           │││││
┌─┴─┐     ┌───┴┴┴┴┴───┐       ┌─┴─┐     ┌───┴┴┴┴┴───┐
│WAP│     │Patch Board│       │WAP│     │Patch Board│
└───┘     └───────────┘       └───┘     └───────────┘
```

I want to be able to access devices connected to the patch board from the wireless network, but I haven't set up a system like this before so I'm a bit concerned about issues I might encounter, and how I should go about solving them.

Comment: What are you calling a *"passive'* switch?

Answer (score 0):

You should have no issues adding a WAP to your network.  You can attach the WAP directly to either the router, switch, or even the patch panel. Since you havent given much detail, I am going to assume the router is providing DHCP.  If that is the case, then make sure DHCP is disabled on the WAP (if it has that capability).